# Scraping source of flash (or other videos) of website

Tags: python, video, web-scraping, flash

The script I'm trying to build does just what the title says. I want my script to output the source of the video just by giving the script a webpage with the video. This so that I can play the video through VLC, instead of using a browser (and ultimately completing the whole automation of this process).

[Example site](http://www.dumpert.nl/mediabase/6801277/9f7c6290/max_verdedigt_tegen_rosberg.html)

[Source address](http://media.dumpert.nl/tablet/9f7c6290_Verstappen_vs._Rosberg_with_Horner_Smile___Streamable.mp4.mp4.mp4)
(Seems to throw forbidden error sometimes in my browser, although can perfectly load it using vlc. Open vlc, hit ctrl+n, enter the url and hit enter)

First I tried to look if there was (for this page) a consistent page-url to source-url conversion, but this seems to not be the case.

The only way I can find to consistantly (so not only for this page, but also other websites) obtain the source code is by doing the following. I open the website in Google Chrome, hit F12 and click on the network tab (to make things show up, refresh the webpage again). There we see a whole list of addresses of loaded things, including the source of the video.

I tried my best to Google my way into finding how to automate this, but with no success.

Does anyone have an idea how to automate this, in python preferably?

Comment: There is no silver bullet, each site is different.

Comment: You might be right there, but all sites I am interested in have either a link in the network tab that ends with something like .mp4 or .m3u8. So far for me that link has always been the source of the video I would like to have.

Comment: Are you scraping a specfic domain?

Comment: Probably a couple, wouldn't mind creating an unique handler for each page.